# SwiftでのISO8601 duration の変換について

Tags: swift, youtube-data-api

SwiftでのYoutube Data APIを利用しており、動画の再生時間を取得したのですが値が

```
"duration": "PT6M33S",
```

とISO8601形式で返ってきます。

これを`String 06:33`に変換して `Label`に用いたいのですが、適切な書き方がわかりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple提供のフレームワークにはISO-8601の[Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)形式(なぜか日本語版のWikiにはDurationsの記述がごっそり抜けています)をパースするためのメソッド等は用意されておらず、自分で書かないといけないようです。

Objective-Cですが、本家のstackoverflowでも多数の回答が寄せられていて、百花繚乱状態ですね。
[How to parse an ISO-8601 duration in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146416/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-duration-in-objective-c)
この中から一番良さそうなもの(`NSScanner`か`sscanf`のどちらかでしょう)を選んでSwiftに直しても良いのですが、ここでは正規表現(`NSRegularExpression`)を使うやり方を紹介しておきます。

```
let iso8601DurationPattern = "^PT(?:(\\d+)H)?(?:(\\d+)M)?(?:(\\d+)S)?$"
let iso8601DurationRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: iso8601DurationPattern, options: [])

let duration = "PT1H6M33S"

if let match = iso8601DurationRegex.firstMatchInString(duration, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<duration.utf16.count)) {
    let hRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let hStr = (hRange.location != NSNotFound) ? (duration as NSString).substringWithRange(hRange) : ""
    let hInt = Int(hStr) ?? 0
    let mRange = match.rangeAtIndex(2)
    let mStr = (mRange.location != NSNotFound) ? (duration as NSString).substringWithRange(mRange) : ""
    let mInt = Int(mStr) ?? 0
    let sRange = match.rangeAtIndex(3)
    let sStr = (sRange.location != NSNotFound) ? (duration as NSString).substringWithRange(sRange) : ""
    let sInt = Int(sStr) ?? 0
    let durationFormatted =
        (hInt == 0)
        ? String(format: "%02d:%02d", mInt, sInt)
        : String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hInt, mInt, sInt)
} else {
    print("bad format")
}
```

[Youtube Video APIの解説](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties)では「`PT#M#S`の形式」と明記してあるのですが、ほんの少しだけ一般化して、「時間」"H"までは入れられるようにしてあります。と言うわけで返ってくる文字列は"PTnHnMnS"の形式(nは10進数、"nH", "nM", "nS"はn=0なら省略可能)と言うのを正規表現にしたのが`iso8601DurationPattern`になります。

もし実際にこのコードを利用されるなら、`NSRegularExpression`のインスタンス作成はかなり重い処理なので、`iso8601DurationRegex`のように`NSRegularExpression`のインスタンスを保持する変数は、グローバル変数かstaticプロパティにしておいた方が良いでしょう。

上に書いたように、正規表現はこの程度の文字列を解析するだけに使うには少し重いので、必ずしもお勧めできる手段とは言えないのですが、文字列処理をする際の道具の一つとして使えるようになっておくと、色々な場面で役に立つ時がでてくると思います。